# Not able to deploy Ethereum PoA Template in Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, blockchain, ethereum

When I try to run the Ethereum Consortium Leader solution template in Azure it keeps failing when trying to deploy in VMExtensionProvisioning.

Short Message is:

```
"status": "Failed",
"error": {
    "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
    "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
    "details": [
        {
            "code": "VMExtensionProvisioningError",
            "message": "VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'config'. Error message: \"Enable failed: failed to execute command: command terminated with exit status=5\n[stdout]\namd64 Packages [5,728 B]\nGet:38 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse Translation-en [2,708 B]\nFetched 14.6 MB in 3s (4,165 kB/s)\nReading package lists...\nReading package lists...\nBuilding dependency tree...\nReading state information...\nThe following additional packages will be installed:\n  libonig2 python3-software-properties\nThe following NEW packages will be installed:\n  jq libonig2\nThe following packages will be upgraded:\n  python3-software-properties software-properties-common\n2 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 243 not upgraded.\nNeed to get 260 kB of archives.\nAfter this operation, 797 kB of additional disk space will be used.\nGet:1 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 libonig2 amd64 5.9.6-1ubuntu0.1 [86.7 kB]\nGet:2 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 jq amd64 1.5+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1 [144 kB]\nGet:3 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 software-properties-common all 0.96.20.9 [9,452 B]\nGet:4 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 python3-software-properties all 0.96.20.9 [20.1 kB]\nFetched 260 kB in 0s (16.6 MB/s)\nSelecting previously unselected package libonig2:amd64.\r\n(Reading database ... \r(Reading database ... 5%\r(Reading database ... 10%\r(Reading database ... 15%\r(Reading database ... 20%\r(Reading database ... 25%\r(Reading database ... 30%\r(Reading database ... 35%\r(Reading database ... 40%\r(Reading database ... 45%\r(Reading database ... 50%\r(Reading database ... 55%\r(Reading database ... 60%\r(Reading database ... 65%\r(Reading database ... 70%\r(Reading database ... 75%\r(Reading database ... 80%\r(Reading database ... 85%\r(Reading database ... 90%\r(Reading database ... 95%\r(Reading database ... 100%\r(Reading database ... 62721 files and directories currently installed.)\r\nPreparing to unpack .../libonig2_5.9.6-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb ...\r\nUnpacking libonig2:amd64 (5.9.6-1ubuntu0.1) ...\r\nSelecting previously unselected package jq.\r\nPreparing to unpack .../jq_1.5+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb ...\r\nUnpacking jq (1.5+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1) ...\r\nPreparing to unpack .../software-properties-common_0.96.20.9_all.deb ...\r\nUnpacking software-properties-common (0.96.20.9) over (0.96.20.7) ...\r\nPreparing to unpack .../python3-software-properties_0.96.20.9_all.deb ...\r\nUnpacking python3-software-properties (0.96.20.9) over (0.96.20.7) ...\r\nProcessing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...\r\nProcessing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...\r\nProcessing triggers for dbus (1.10.6-1ubuntu3.3) ...\r\nSetting up libonig2:amd64 (5.9.6-1ubuntu0.1) ...\r\nSetting up jq (1.5+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1) ...\r\nSetting up python3-software-properties (0.96.20.9) ...\r\nSetting up software-properties-common (0.96.20.9) ...\r\nProcessing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...\r\ndeb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli/ xenial main\nExecuting: /tmp/tmp.w88yTiua77/gpg.1.sh --keyserver\npackages.microsoft.com\n--recv-keys\n52E16F86FEE04B979B07E28DB02C46DF417A0893\nError: Import packages.microsoft.com server keys failed.. Failed after 1 attempts with exit code 2, retrying...\nExecuting: /tmp/tmp.loSAcg8eVv/gpg.1.sh --keyserver\npackages.microsoft.com\n--recv-keys\n52E16F86FEE04B979B07E28DB02C46DF417A0893\nError: Import packages.microsoft.com server keys failed.. Failed after 2 attempts with exit code 2, retrying...\nExecuting: /tmp/tmp.PYWGe2pnCu/gpg.1.sh --keyserver\npackages.microsoft.com\n--recv-keys\n52E16F86FEE04B979B07E28DB02C46DF417A0893\nError: Import packages.microsoft.com server keys failed.. Failed after 3 attempts with exit code 2, retrying...\nExecuting: /tmp/tmp.sFS1yTk3LA/gpg.1.sh --keyserver\npackages.microsoft.com\n--recv-keys\n52E16F86FEE04B979B07E28DB02C46DF417A0893\nError: Import packages.microsoft.com server keys failed.. Failed after 4 attempts with exit code 2, retrying...\nExecuting: /tmp/tmp.6y5bPFWh2G/gpg.1.sh --keyserver\npackages.microsoft.com\n--recv-keys\n52E16F86FEE04B979B07E28DB02C46DF417A0893\nError: Import packages.microsoft.com server keys failed.. Failed after 5 attempts with exit code 2, retrying...\n\n[stderr]\n--2020-04-03 14:04:36--  https://catalogartifact.azureedge.net/publicartifacts/microsoft-azure-blockchain.azure-blockchain-ethereum-853e9e69-7826-45bf-992b-225b43c52061-ethereum-poa-consortium/Artifacts/scripts/poa-utility.sh\nResolving catalogartifact.azureedge.net (catalogartifact.azureedge.net)... 13.107.246.10, 2620:1ec:bdf::10\nConnecting to catalogartifact.azureedge.net (catalogartifact.azureedge.net)|13.107.246.10|:443... connected.\nHTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK\nLength: 4296 (4.2K) [application/json]\nSaving to: ‘poa-utility.sh’\n\n     0K ....                                                  100%  854M=0s\n\n2020-04-03 14:04:36 (854 MB/s) - ‘poa-utility.sh’ saved [4296/4296]\n\n--2020-04-03 14:04:36--  https://catalogartifact.azureedge.net/publicartifacts/microsoft-azure-blockchain.azure-blockchain-ethereum-853e9e69-7826-45bf-992b-225b43c52061-ethereum-poa-consortium/Artifacts/scripts/configure-validator.sh\nResolving catalogartifact.azureedge.net (catalogartifact.azureedge.net)... 13.107.246.10, 2620:1ec:bdf::10\nConnecting to catalogartifact.azureedge.net (catalogartifact.azureedge.net)|13.107.246.10|:443... connected.\nHTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK\nLength: 12841 (13K) [application/json]\nSaving to: ‘configure-validator.sh’\n\n     0K .......... ..                                         100%  127M=0s\n\n2020-04-03 14:04:36 (127 MB/s) - ‘configure-validator.sh’ saved [12841/12841]\n\n--2020-04-03 14:04:36--  https://catalogartifact.azureedge.net/publicartifacts/microsoft-azure-blockchain.azure-blockchain-ethereum-853e9e69-7826-45bf-992b-225b43c52061-ethereum-poa-consortium/Artifacts/scripts/run-validator.sh\nResolving catalogartifact.azureedge.net (catalogartifact.azureedge.net)... 13.107.246.10, 2620:1ec:bdf::10\nConnecting to catalogartifact.azureedge.net (catalogartifact.azureedge.net)|13.107.246.10|:443... connected.\nHTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK\nLength: 7460 (7.3K) [application/json]\nSaving to: ‘run-validator.sh’\n\n     0K .......                                               100%  613M=0s\n\n2020-04-03 14:04:37 (613 MB/s) - ‘run-validator.sh’ saved [7460/7460]\n\n--2020-04-03 14:04:37--  https://catalogartifact.azureedge.net/publicartifacts/microsoft-azure-blockchain.azure-blockchain-ethereum-853e9e69-7826-45bf-992b-225b43c52061-ethereum-poa-consortium/Artifacts/scripts/backup-poa.sh\nResolving catalogartifact.azureedge.net (catalogartifact.azureedge.net)... 13.107.246.10, 2620:1ec:bdf::10\nConnecting to catalogartifact.azureedge.net (catalogartifact.azureedge.net)|13.107.246.10|:443... connected.\nHTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK\nLength: 1652 (1.6K) [application/json]\nSaving to: ‘backup-poa.sh’\n\n     0K .                                                     100%  335M=0s\n\n2020-04-03 14:04:37 (335 MB/s) - ‘backup-poa.sh’ saved [1652/1652]\n\ndebconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog\ndebconf: (Dialog frontend will not work on a dumb terminal, an emacs shell buffer, or without a controlling terminal.)\ndebconf: falling back to frontend: Readline\ndebconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline\ndebconf: (This frontend requires a controlling tty.)\ndebconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype\ndpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin: \ngpg: requesting key 417A0893 from hkp server packages.microsoft.com\ngpg: keyserver timed out\ngpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error\ngpg: requesting key 417A0893 from hkp server packages.microsoft.com\ngpg: keyserver timed out\ngpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error\ngpg: requesting key 417A0893 from hkp server packages.microsoft.com\ngpg: keyserver timed out\ngpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error\ngpg: requesting key 417A0893 from hkp server packages.microsoft.com\ngpg: keyserver timed out\ngpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error\ngpg: requesting key 417A0893 from hkp server packages.microsoft.com\ngpg: keyserver timed out\ngpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error\n\"\r\n\r\nMore information on troubleshooting is available at https://aka.ms/VMExtensionCSELinuxTroubleshoot "
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been fixed, a new version of Ethereum on Azure template is available on Azure Marketplace [here](https://ms.portal.azure.com/#create/hub)